# jQuery call to WCF Service parameter comes through as null

Tags: asp.net, wcf, jquery

I've got an ASP.NET page that calls a WCF Service using jQuery.  The page passes in the contents of a text box control to the service.  The service uses this text box value to look up a record and then it returns a POCO to the jQuery to update the contents of a bunch of other controls.

At least, that is what I am trying to make happen.

So far, my problem is that the string parameter that is passed into my WCF Operation is always null.  I think I must not be handling the jQuery part properly.  I can find lots of examples of jQuery calls to WCF services without parameters or with hard-coded parameters and I've spent a lot of time and looked at a lot of questions here on SO and on other sites.  Still no luck.  I even have another WCF service that is being called by jQuery .autocomplete on the same page and this is working just fine.

When I trace the network traffic, I can see that I'm getting a request going through.  The request looks like this:

```
GET /Services/UserByEmailService.svc/GetUserByEmail?{"email":%20"jbrown@mooseware.ca"}
```

Here is my jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#txtEmail").blur(function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/Services/UserByEmailService.svc/GetUserByEmail",
            data: '{"email": "' + $("#txtEmail").val() + '"}',
            processData: false,
            success: function (response) {
                $("#lblUserID").html = response.d.UID;
                $("#txtOrganization").html = response.d.Organization;
                $("#txtPhone").html = response.d.Phone;
                $("#txtName").html = response.d.Name;
                $("#txtNotes").html = response.d.Name;
                $("#hdnUserKey").html = response.d.Syskey;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is what my WCF Service code looks like...

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class UserByEmailService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(UserLookupResult))]
    [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, 
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public UserLookupResult GetUserByEmail(string email)
    {
        UserLookupResult oResult = new UserLookupResult();
        try
        {
            using (DownloadDBEntities ctx = new DownloadDBEntities())
            {
                DownloadDB.User oUser = ctx.Users.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Email == email);
                if (oUser != null)
                {
                    oResult.Syskey = oUser.Syskey.ToString();
                    oResult.UID = oUser.UserID;
                    oResult.Name = oUser.Name;
                    oResult.Organization = oUser.Organization;
                    oResult.Phone = oUser.Phone;
                    oResult.Notes = oUser.Notes;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {   // For debugging only...
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        return oResult;
    }
}

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class UserLookupResult
{
    public string Syskey { get; set; }
    public string UID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Organization { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public UserLookupResult()
    {
        Syskey = string.Empty;
        UID = string.Empty;
        Name = string.Empty;
        Organization = string.Empty;
        Phone = string.Empty;
        Notes = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

I can trace this code and it executes when I expect it to.  However, the string argument of the `GetUserByEmail` method (`email`) is always null, even though I can see that a value is being passed in via the request (see above).

Can anyone point me a a working example of a jQuery call that passes a text value to a WCF service on blur of a control so that a lookup can be performed using the control contents?  Is there something you can see that I'm getting wrong in my JavaScript or WCF service definition?

**EDIT: Here Is My Resolution...**

Many thanks to IAbstractDownvoteFactor, Matt Phillips and darthjit for the assistance on this problem.  In the end, I was able to resolve the problem with a variation on the `data` argument of my `$.ajax` call.  This is what ended up working for me:

```
data: { "email": $("#txtEmail").val() },
```

Note that the difference between what I had originally and what eventually worked is that my data argument had to be passed as a JSON object with a quoted key value.

I don't know if this is going to bite me eventually or if this solution would generalize to a service with multiple arguments.  I had originally tried marshalling the data argument as a JSON string because of something I read in [Encosia's Blog](http://encosia.com/3-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-jquery-with-aspnet-ajax/) - which points out that jQuery will try to URL encode the data object instead of passing it on to your web service directly.  I had even seen another blog post, which I can't find at the momement, that said it mattered whether your outer quotes were double or single quotes.

**Also:** As Matt pointed out, I also needed to have `processData = true,` which I got by default by removing this argument from the `$.ajax` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're input field id is not spelled exactly `txtEmail` it will return null because it won't find the input and `val()` won't do anything for you. Can you look in fiddler or some sort of http listener to see what the url itself is that the ajax call is posting to?

EDIT:
Looking at the option `processData` for the `$.ajax` call.
From the jquery docs

```
processDataBoolean
Default: true
By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other      
than a string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the     
default     
content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send a DOMDocument, or     
other non-processed data, set this option to false
```

Try changing that to true and see if that helps.

Comment: The IE 9 network tracer says the http GET is going to this URL: (as noted originally): `GET /Services/UserByEmailService.svc/GetUserByEmail?{"email":%20"jbrown@mooseware.ca"}`  I'm pretty confident that the control is being picked up.

Comment: Ok, so why is it that instead of `/Services/UserByEmailService.svc/GetUserByEmail?email=jbrown@mooseware.ca` I believe it's trying to turn your json into the string email variable and it doesn't understand it so it ends up being null.

Comment: Matt.  The problem turned out to be how jQuery was interpreting the `data` argument as well as the value of `processData`.  You can see the details in my edited question.  Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: No problem. AJAX and JQuery are powerful tools, but I've found that sometimes silly changes like that are all that separates frustration from exhilaration :)

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
data: '{"email": "' + $("#txtEmail").val() + '"}',
```

should be:

```
data: {email: $("#txtEmail").val()},
```

jQuery can't assume that your string is an object, so it simply sends the string. But jQuery knows exactly what to do with an object.

Comment: IAbstract, thanks for the answer.  It turned out that I needed a variation of this - see my edited question for details.  You got me on the road to a solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

couple of suggestions:

1. You may need to set the binding webHttpBinding so that your service is REST-ful
2. you may have to set the URI template like this

[OperationContract]
[WebGet( UriTemplate="GetUserBYEmail?email={email}" )]
public UserLookupResult GetUserByEmail(string email)

Comment: darthjit, thanks very much for the suggestions.  I tried these out and it lead me down a rabbit hole of compiler errors and manual .config changes.  UriTemplate doesn't play well with 'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebScriptEnablingBehavior'.